# Trial column in client statictics SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, ssms, sqlperformance

I start attach Client Statistics to examinate my queries. There are "Trial x" columns, What do they mean?

I use SQL Server 2014

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trial X column specifies the number of times you execute the query. Trial column creates each time when you execute the query. Maximum of last 10 trial statistics will be shown. Average values of the trial will be shown in Average column.

> MSDN says it “Displays information about the query execution grouped
>   into categories. When Include Client Statistics is selected from the
>   Query menu, a Client Statistics window is displayed upon query
>   execution. Statistics from successive query executions are listed
>   along with the average values. Select Reset Client Statistics from the
>   Query menu to reset the average.”

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run a query with include client statistics, SQL Server includes a run history ("Trial n").  This allows you to easily compare recent execution statistics.  The history is generally useful only if you are running the same basic query repeatedly and are making changes that may affect performance.  The up and down arrows indicate progression or digression compared to the previous run.